# Regex to get src of iframe element

Tags: regex, iframe

I am trying to retrieve part of the src from different iframes from an HTML input.

So far, I've tried different methods but none of them works for all iframes. What I've tried so far:

```
<iframe(.*?)><\/iframe>
<iframe src="(.+?)".+</iframe>
<iframe.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>
```

And here is a sample of iframe tags that I have:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NM51qOpwcIM?modestbranding=1;rel=0;showinfo=0;autoplay=0;autohide=1;yt:stretch=16:9;wmode=transparent;?wmode=transparent" allowfullscreen="" style="width: 640px; height: 361.057px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VASywEuqFd8?feature=oembed" allowfullscreen="" width="660" height="371" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Ideally, I would like to retrieve the src from the beginning and just before the first question mark (?) as such:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/NM51qOpwcIM
```

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse `/X?HTML/` with regexes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 10):

This can be achieved using

```
(?<=src=").*?(?=[\?"])
```

See [working example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YtqXxE/1)

### Explanation

1. `(?<=src=")` Prepended by `src="`
2. `.*?` Lazy match any token
3. `(?=[\?"])` Until either a `?` or `"` would be the next token

#### If you might have a longer URL that doesn't end with `?`

```
(?<=src=").*?(?=[\*"])
```

Comment: this does not working with ie11 browser. what will be solution that works across browsers ?

Comment: Works for me in IE11 too.

Comment: `(?<=src=").*?(?=[*"])`

No need to escape `*` inside the `[]` because we're specifying chars to filter inside the square brace.